# console application async/await not returning my list

Tags: c#, async-await

Why doesn't the following compile? I'm just trying to get a simple list to return.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var list = MainAsync(args).Wait();
            //Compile error: Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed variable
        }

        static async Task MainAsync(string[] args)
        {
            Bootstrapper bs = new Bootstrapper();
            var list = await bs.GetList();
        }
    }

    public class Bootstrapper
    {
        public async Task<List<string>> GetList()
        {
            List<string> toReturn = new List<string>();
            toReturn.Add("hello");
            toReturn.Add("world");
            return await toReturn;
            //Compile error: 'List<string>' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'List<string>'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What compile error are you getting?

Comment: why `await` in return statement?

Comment: Updated code with compile errors. New to async/await, so I'm just trying something simple to try to understand.

Comment: `MainAsync` doesn't return a value.  Why are you trying to store a result into `list` here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no use case here to make this method `async`, just return a `List<string>`

```
public List<string> GetList()
{
    List<string> toReturn = new List<string>();
    toReturn.Add("hello");
    toReturn.Add("world");
    return toReturn;
}
```

However, if there were some *IO* or otherwise `async` calls you needed to make in `GetList`, then you could do the following

```
public async Task<List<string>> GetList()
{
    // now we have a reason to be async (barely)
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    List<string> toReturn = new List<string>();
    toReturn.Add("hello");
    toReturn.Add("world");
    return toReturn;
}
```

Update

or another way to simulate an `async` workload is `Task.FromResult`

```
private async Task<List<string>> Test()
{
    List<string> toReturn = new List<string>();
    toReturn.Add("hello");
    toReturn.Add("world");
    return await Task.FromResult(toReturn);
}
```

**Update**

As mentioned by Sir Rufo, there is a lot to this `async` and `await` a good place to start is with [Stephen Cleary](https://blog.stephencleary.com/), he is a very well articulated blogger on such topics

Comment: I was just trying to simulate a database call that would populate the list

Comment: Because OP is new to async/await you should mention ConfigureAwait(false) otherwise you send him into a future deadlock

Comment: @Rod Read the [blog of Stephen Cleary](https://blog.stephencleary.com/) where you find a lot of async/await

Comment: ConfigureAwait(false) is only necessary when you fired off a task in a UI synchronization context (also asp.net request context) because all work is scheduled on the UI thread by default. A console app isn't going to have that issue because it will schedule tasks on the thread pool thread. I would also recommend this book by Cleary: https://www.amazon.com/Concurrency-Cookbook-Asynchronous-Multithreaded-Programming/dp/1449367569